# antd Notification in Context not opening?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I am using `Notification` from antd wrapped in a context as I intend to call the different notifications in other pages. However, in my development build, I encountered the following error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Request failed with status code 500). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated!

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cohen-sno4f)

[Error Message in Next.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcaDY.png)

Comment: could your please share nextjs code which generates the error?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan my nextjs code is actually quite barebones right now, and it is purely CSR for now! it is pretty much the same as the code sandbox for now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found that I was passing in an object as a description into the notification APIs, hence React was not able to render it since it was not an Element or a string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).